Is there a way to call the default move operator from a non-default one?
I have this class:
struct Handle
{
    int* ptr_to_something;
    void operator=(Handle&& other)
    {
        ptr_to_something = other.ptr_to_something;
        this->member1 = other.member1;
        this->member2 = other.member2;
        this->member3 = other.member3;
        
        other.ptr_to_something = nullptr;
        
    }
    
    int member1;
    int member2;
    int member3;
};

What I hate is possibility that new members might be added, and I'll have to remember to add them to the operator. Is there possibly a way I could call the default operator and then add that teensy little but that sets the other ptr to null after it?

First of all follow rule 350. Next comes the principle of separation of concerns: The only member that needs special treatment is the pointer; so you need to isolate and encapsulate in some smart pointer class, then follow rule 0 from the  rule 350. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Some small remarks : this-> is not needed. And for anything other than int members your move assignment might not be correct. Learn to use member1 = std::move(other.member1);

You can have a base class with a defaulted move operator:
struct HandlerBase {
    int* ptr_to_something;
    int member1;
    int member2;
    int member3;
};

struct Handler : HandlerBase {
    void operator=(Handler&& other) {
        HandlerBase::operator=(std::move(other));
        other.ptr_to_something = nullptr;
    }
};

Or you can make the defaulted move operator do what you want by making ptr_to_something a class whose operator= does what you want:
template<typename T>
struct PtrThatResetsOnMove {
    T* value;

    constexpr explicit(false) PtrThatResetsOnMove(T* value) noexcept : value(value) {}
    constexpr PtrThatResetsOnMove(PtrThatResetsOnMove&& other) noexcept : value(std::exchange(other.value, nullptr)) {}
    constexpr PtrThatResetsOnMove& operator=(PtrThatResetsOnMove&& other) noexcept {
        value = std::exchange(other.value, nullptr);
        return *this;
    }
    ~PtrThatResetsOnMove() = default;
};

struct Handler {
    PtrThatResetsOnMove<int> ptr_to_something;
    int member1;
    int member2;
    int member3;
};

Or you can put the other members in a different class with a defaulted operator:
struct HandlerMembers {
    int member1;
    int member2;
    int member3;
};

struct Handler {
    int* ptr_to_something;
    HandlerMembers members;
    void operator=(Handler&& other) {
       ptr_to_something = other.ptr_to_something;
       members = std::move(other.members);
       other.ptr_to_something = nullptr;
    }
};


PtrThatResetsOnMove is possibly just unique_ptr, maybe with a null deleter if that's the desired behaviour
